# Update GIT sources from perforce repository

Tags: git, perforce

We used to maintain all our sources in GIT and later again moved to perforce. Again we want to merge all the sources from perforce to GIT repository. GIT has the same directory structure as perforce. Now i want to get all the latest sources from perforce repository and merge it in the GIT repository. How do i merge the GIT repository by getting he latest sources from perforce repository.

Comment: `p4 sync`, followed by `git add`, `git commit`? Or are you asking a more sophisticated question than that?